# Divi custom module render shortcode

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode, divi

I am trying to build a custom Divi module. I need to render a shortcode, it works in the frontend but in editor, the shortcode simply displays as a plaintext. How can I render shortcode in Divi editor?
Divi uses react and I am not too good at it.

This is my code in .jsx file -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class divi_custom_module extends Component {

  static slug = 'divi_custom_module';

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.props.heading}</h2>
        <div>
            [my-shortcode title={this.props.title}]
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default divi_custom_module;
```

[image]